# Is there a limitation of n_jobs in Scikit Learn GridSearchCV where it must be less than the number of cv folds?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, parallel-processing, gridsearchcv

I'm running a GridSearchCV on a hpc cluster with 64 cores available. I'm using 10 cv folds and n_jobs=40:

```
param_grid = [{'n_estimators': list(range(20, 200, 20)), 'criterion': ['mse', 'mae']}]
regcv = model_selection.GridSearchCV(RandomForestRegressor(), param_grid, cv=10, n_jobs=40, verbose=1)
regcv.fit(train , labels)
```

I have noticed that there is only 10 processes running on my cluster even tho I've stipulated 40. I've also tried running the GridSearchCV with n_jobs=20 and again there are only 10 processes running on my cluster.

Is it possible to have more n_jobs than cv folds?

Comment: the jobs are split by the provided CV, not by the parameter grid. You could however divide up the parameters yourself and run them in parallel.

Comment: So if the jobs are split by the provided CV it is never possible to have n_jobs > cv (without manually running as you mention)?

Comment: I don't see how. Have a look at the `BaseSearchCV` class' `fit` method.

Comment: Yes, I've looked through the code and cannot see anywhere where n_jobs is limited by CV. But that is why I'm confused that I'm only ever seeing 10 processes on my machine when n_jobs=40?

Comment: You're right, `Parallel` is invoked with the product of `cv.split()` and the parameters... strange

Comment: What's the size of your parameter grid?

Comment: I've edited the question to include my parameter grid. 11 options in the grid.